# Increment ID value automatically to pass the id in url

Tags: php, html, url, href

I have a small project in which i have different news. In the main php page i.e news_all.php i have shown only the small information about news. And when user clicks on any news the complete news will be shown on different page i.e news.php. I have decalre variable $newsId with value and pass it into a href id so that i can take the id from url and identify and display complete news in news.php. But i have many news and i dont want to declare variables for every news and pass it into every news to identify it.I think its not great idea.I just want to decalre only 1 variable and increment the value and pass it into a href id to identify  news.Thanks.
Here is my code for news_all.php

```
if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-news')
{
    $newsId = 1;
    $page['register-news'] = array(
        1   => array( 'News','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),

    );

    $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-news']).'</div>
                '.CreateMessage().'
                <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="tab1" class="tab" style="display:block">
                            <table id="news">
<div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_269_kurz">
**<a href="news.php?id='.$newsId.'"** class="TrackNews" id="01" target="_blank">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Montag, 19.05.2014</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">Teilnahme von MAN Top Used an der Samoter 2014</p>
<div class="newsText">
<p class="welcome-text"><img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/man-it.jpg" width="165" class="text_fixed" border="0"></p>
<p class="welcome-text">Die 29. Internationale Erd- und Bautechnik-Ausstellung Samoter fand zwischen dem 8. und 11. Mai in Verona statt und zog rund 100.000 Besucher an. Samoter ist die wichtigste italienische Messe ihrer Art, die den Themen Erdbewegung, Hochbau und Baumaschinen gewidmet ist. Zugleich ist diese Veranstaltung damit auch f? europ?chen Markt bedeutsam.</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_264_kurz">
<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="02" target="_blank">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Freitag, 24.01.2014</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">Kaufvertrag: neue Porsche-Vorlage zum Drucken!</p>
<div class="newsText">
<img src="http://intern.autodo.de/admin/news/porsche-kaufvertrag.jpg" border="0" align="right" class="img_fixed" width=60><p class="welcome-text">Ihr AMO Druckcenter bietet Ihnen ab sofort die M?chkeit, Kaufvertr? im Porsche-Design zu nutzen.</p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" id="news_265_kurz">
<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="03" target="_blank">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Mittwoch, 15.01.2014</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">AutoDo! Update: Die Eigenschaft -Unfallfahrzeug- wurde im AMO erweitert!</p>
<div class="newsText">
<p class="welcome-text">Ab sofort k?n Sie Fahrzeuge nach folgenden Kriterien kennzeichnen:</p>
<p class="highlight"><b>? Unfallfahrzeug<br>
? Unfallfrei<br>
? Keine Angabe</b></p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<div class="welcome-rahmen krz toggleNews" id="news_262_kurz">
<a href="news.php?id=" class="TrackNews" id="04" target="_blank">
<p class="welcome-breadcrump">Dezember 2013</p>
<p class="welcome-subheadline">NUR OFFLINE!:<br>Machen Sie Ihre Preise fit f? Zukunft:<br>attraktive Preisregulierung mit dem neuen Preismanagement!</p>
<div class="newsText" style="display:none;">
<p class="welcome-text">Entscheiden Sie sich jetzt f? Erweiterungsmodul <b>AMO</b><i>profi!</i> und sichern Sie sich neben umfangreichen Auswertungsm?chkeiten und einem automatischen B?ncheck das brandneue Preismanagement mit folgenden Vorteilen:</p>
<p class="page-breadcrump">AutoDo!-Team</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Are the news stored on db?

Comment: You're not incrementing $newsId, try $newsId++

Comment: Hi no the news are not stored in database and i have tried $newsID++ but it will increment the id for next news but not for the other news . Do i need to use loop ?

Comment: How do you plan to identify the news on the server from the id on the website, or asking other way round: If you receive a request for "id=1", how do you know which news the user has seen? The ID must be stored with the news, and is applied to the news record on creation. When listing the news, the php needs to prepare your news with the id given on creation.

Comment: I think storing the id in database is another way and its easy too but cant we have any other way here or logic to increment the id automatically ?

Comment: if you are not displaying data from db there is no clean way you can do it. 1)get the data from db 2) increment a counter on id of news on the php loop html rendering code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any loop for iterating news here... You can just initialize $newsId = 1; and then place $newsId++ on anchor tag

```
<a href="news.php?id='.$newsId++.'"** class="TrackNews" id="01" target="_blank">
```

I think It would work.. if not you can explain your question  more.

Comment: what are these asterisks?

Comment: It's given in questionair HTML

Comment: I have tried man of using $newsId++ but its now working and i guess it will only increment id for second news but i have many news.And my question is simple i have to increment the id while using only 1 variable and pass it into href id to identify every news. So when user click on first news it will news.php?id=1, for second news news.php?id=2 and so on...

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal oh yes i think op tried to make the text **bold** there

Comment: @user3702602 please use the variable `$_GET['id']` which holds whatever value the news.php? **id=123123** has

Comment: i am using  $_GET['id'] in news.page page to display complete information about news. But this id is coming from news_all.php page where i have question.

Comment: You need to put your <div class="welcome-rahmen lng toggleNews" in loop and then use same variable for news... other way we can do it by using jQuery